# Vue - Call a method from a different component (uses vue-routes)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Here is my base `App.vue` that holds the `router-view`:

```
<template>
<div>
    <Navbar/>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import Navbar from './components/Navbar.vue';

export default {
    name: 'App',
    components: {
        Navbar
    }
}
</script>
```

In the `Navbar.vue`, I have a method:

```
methods: {
    getLoggedStatus(){
        console.log('asdasd')
    }
}
```

Lastly, I have a `Login.vue` that is loaded there on the `router-view`. I wanna acess the `getLoggedStatus()` from the `Navbar.vue` within `Login.vue`. How can I achieve this?

I tried putting a ref to the `Navbar` tag in `App.vue`:

```
<Navbar ref="navvy"/>
```

And calling in on the `Login.vue` with:

```
this.$refs.navvy.getLoggedStatus()
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Because `refs` is available in App.vue context i.e. `this`, not in Login.vue.

IMHO I don't think it's a good strategy to get loggedStatus like this.

Comment: @hamzox any suggestions? :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A ref only works on children. You're rendering `<Navbar>` within app, so you cannot call that ref from login. You can only access `this.$refs.navvy` from `App.vue`.

There are several solutions for your problem.

1. #### Emit an event from Login to App, so App calls the method from a ref.

You can set a listener in the router-view, as:

```
<router-view  @loggedStatus="callLoggedStatus"  />
```

In your login, when you would want to call the navbar `getLoggedStatus`, you would instead emit that event:

```
this.$emit('loggedStatus')
```

And then in App.vue, you would defined a `callLoggedStatus` methods that call the ref:

```
callLoggedStatus() {
  this.$refs.navvy.getLoggedStatus();
}
```

Given that you add the ref to the `<Navbar>` component in the APP template.

This solution is arguably the most similar to your proposed code, but I think it is a mess and you should avoid it, since you can end up listening to a lot of different events in your App.vue.

2. #### Use Vuex

I don't exactly know what `getLoggedStatus` does, but if you want to change how your navbar behaves when the user is logged in, you should probably setup a vuex store, so you register there wether the user is logged or not. Then in your navbar component you render things conditionally depending upon the user is logged or not.

@Lana's answer follows this idea, and is probably the closest to the official way to thins in Vue.

3. #### Use an event emitter

If you want to directly communicate between components that are not in the same family, I think an event emitter is a reasonable choice. You could setup an application wide event emitter after creating the app:

```
const app = new Vue({...});
window.emitter = new Vue();
```

(in the example we use a new Vue as event emitter. There is also the 'events'  module which allow to use a EventEmitter)

And then any component can use it to send messages, so Login could do:

```
window.emitter.$emit('user-logged', myCustomPayload);
```

And Navbar on the other hand could do:

```
window.emitter.$on('user-logged', function() {
  this.getLoggedStatus();
})
```

This last option is not well considered in the Vue community -Vuex is preferred- but for small applications I think it is the simplest.

4. #### The dirty hack

You can always export your component to window. In the Navbar `created` hook you could do:

```
created() {
  window.Navbar = this;
}
```

And then in Login.vue you could, at any time:

```
window.Navbar.getLoggedStatus()
```

And it will work. However, this is surely an anti pattern and can cause a lot of harm to your project maintainability if you start doing this with several components.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! I'll try this.

Comment: Number 3 was the perfect in my case. I had to add `window.emitter = new Vue();` in the `main.js` file. And I changed just a little bit this part: I used `window.emitter.$on("your-event", (value) => {yourMethod();}`

Answer (score 3):

It looks like `getLoggedStatus` returns some global state of the app. Use [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) for managing these global variables.

Create a store like this:

```
// Make sure to call Vue.use(Vuex) first if using a module system
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    loggedStatus: 0
  },
  getters: {
    getLoggedStatus: state => {
      // to compute derived state based on store state
      return state.loggedStatus 
    }
  }
})
```

Use `store.state.loggedStatus` in any Vue-component to access the global state or use getters like `store.getters.getLoggedStatus` if you need to compute derived state based on store state.